# How should I minify my menus?

Tags: mobile, menu, sidebar, hamburger, optimisation

I design a dashboard for a service. I have a main menu at the top of the browser. The menu has 5 points and take up much space. I also have a sidebar on the left to navigate to the selected page.
I'm going to work to optimize for mobile devices and tablets. How am I supposed to roll the menu?

Comment: Is your "main menu" primary and "sidebar menu" secondary? Are elements in sidebar menu children of a selected menu item from your "main menu"?

Comment: @Igorek Yes, "main menu" is primary and "sidebar menu" is secondary. Main menu looks like category of the dashboard, for example - settings. And sidebar helps to navigate on current page, for example on the settings in sidebar you can see: profile, site, subscription and etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry for the late reply ...*

[Google's Material Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage) have documented many of the common solutions to this problem. Following are a few examples that I've had success with.

## Discovery is critical

The notorious hamburger menu proliferated in answer to the need to cram complex navigation into a mobile view. The unsurprising side effect was obscuring information architecture and important feature sets. Product owners just about everywhere noticed that navigation hidden behind the hamburger saw notably lower engagement than their persistently available counterparts.

**How do we enable discovery within a limited viewport?** Workflows and curation. Evaluate how users move through your application (data you should already have) and how you might be able to improve that. Take that data and map out the when, where, and why of their navigation needs. Design your navigation around that map.

## When discovery isn't critical

You'll find that not everything fits. There are views and actions that fall into the "only when they're looking for it" category. These are things that users expect to find somewhere, often behind the hamburger. Components that fit this category can include sign out, profile settings, account info, etc.

## Top-level hierarchy

Mobile has a familiar pattern for top level views, illustrated well by Google's framework:

[image: Material top nav]

In this example, "All" can be tapped to reveal it's sibling views:

[image: Material top nav menu]

In this case, it's often best to start from some kind of "Dashboard" or main page where all the top-level views are available side-by-side. Moving down into any one of them switches to this format.

## Child categories

The potential depth of child categories is what drives many people to just toss a hamburger in. But, if you can streamline this group, tabs are a great solution.

[image: Material tabs]

In this example, the tabs scroll left and right to reveal overflow. Not ideal, but with careful spacing to allow some "peeking" of additional content most users will discover it. I recommend including an edge shadow or paging arrow (or both) to further emphasize the side-scrolling action.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities if your navigation is fairly simple.

- A horizontal primary navigation will work ok on mobile if you don't have very many items.
- A vertical secondary navigation will probably take up too much screen space on mobile, but you could add this as a second horizontal bar, or possibly a drop-down from the primary navigation.  Again, this depends on not having very many items to display.

I could see something like this being a reasonable compromise if your site is mostly going to be used on the desktop, but might be used occasionally on mobile.

*Note: I responded based on an inappropriate edit to the question, which has now been corrected.  This info might still be useful, but it probably isn't the best answer for the OP's actual question.*

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I didn't say "the same on all devices". I think moderator edited my question.

Comment: @Hola, wow that edit totally changed your question.  I have rolled it back now.  Unfortunately it makes this answer rather irrelevant!

Answer (score -1):

I once designed an experimental page navigation system for my own website for this very reason. Below is my implementation and a step-by-step explanation of how it works:

---

[image: Overview of drop-down menu page navigation]

---

### 1. Open the Main Menu

[image: Opening the Main Menu]

To access the internal page navigation/index, we must open the Main Menu itself. For my goal to keep things as compact as possible, I opted for a more "nested" approach, in which the current page navigation was a subset of the website navigation, aka the Main Menu.

---

### 2. Slide to the Breadcrumb Tray Icon

[image: Sliding to Reveal the Breadcrumb Tray Icon]

> In this design, this step only takes place on smaller sized devices as on larger screens the menu appears as follows:

[image: Main Menu on a Larger Screen]

---

### 3. Open the Breadcrumb Tray

[image: Opening the Breadcrumb Tray]

The Breadcrumb Tray is right-to-left aligned, meaning that in this design the HTML structure is actually in reverse, but gives it an "expected behavior", making certain that the current page shows up first on smaller screens!

> The most appropriate icon I could think of for the Breadcrumb Tray at the time was a file folder, however, you may find a different icon more appropriate.

---

### 4. Open the Page Navigation/Index

[image: Opening the Page Navigation]

Here you can see the Page Navigation combined with the Breadcrumb Tray in a "drop-down" fashion, utilizing the current page as a button itself!

> I managed to set up the page navigation to display the page's hierarchy. It was actually generated using JQuery to pick out the headers of the page and adding classes that matched the header type. I also added a method of adding anchor tags in case any were not available and using existing ones if any were!

---

Overall you can just add your page navigation in a drop down section of your main menu in order to save yourself space, if you want it to be persistent and shown all the time, you can always stick it in either the top of the page or under a sticky navigation bar! Either way you do it should help you save space and suite your needs.

I hope that my own solution helps you find your own as well! Good luck!